# When to refresh a view when iOS app is being recalled from inactive/suspended

Tags: ios5, uiapplicationdelegate

My app has time-sensitive information in a view that will need to be updated, when the app is recalled by the user, from an inactive/suspended state. Which of the two app delegate methods below should handle this?

Here:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{

 //Check to see if we need to refresh a view
 if([self needToRefreshView])
   [viewcontroller1 refreshView];

}
```

or

Here:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{


   //Check to see if we need to refresh a view
   if([self needToRefreshView])
   [viewcontroller1 refreshView];


 }
```

Is one method better suited for this than the other? If so, Why?

Thanks

Comment: Good Apple resource here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those should both work fine, the only other that I would consider implementing your code in is  `viewWillAppear`.